# Number format in Legend Labels

Tags: legending, number-representation

I would like to use the usual (new and nice) `BarLegend[]` with something like

```
BarLegend[{"LakeColors", 1/10000 {-2, 2}}]
```

which looks like

[image: Example BarLegends-Plot]

I don't like the numbers, i would like to use `ScientificForm[]` on them,
hence get $0.0002 = 2\times10^{-4}$ or even better - get just $2$ at the label and $\times 10^{-4}$ in the bottom right or something like that.

Is there a way to obtain `ScientificForm[]` for these labels? I searched the Documentation of the new `~Legends` and haven't found anything. And the very best would be, to be able to specify the number of digits used (where i would like to have 3, e.g. $2.00\times10^{-4}$, so best would be `ScientificForm[#,3] &` to be applied to every number of the Legend.

### Update

Surprisingly - following the approach of @Nasser M. Abbasi the two lines

```
f[x_] := ScientificForm[x, 2];
BarLegend[{"LakeColors", 1/10000 {-2, 2}}, LegendFunction -> f]
```

produce a Legend like

[image: second approach]

Though the second argument of `ScientificForm[]` gets ignored. Any further ideas why that does happen?

### Update #2

Changing `f` to `f[x_] := ScientificForm[N[{x} /. {DirectedInfinity -> Identity}], 2];` actually *does* change the number of digits, but returns the `BarLegend` in an Array and produces errors, that `(1.,4.}` is not a List of positive Integers (though they look quite Integer to me). Why there is an `DirectInfinity` approaching, I haven't found out yet, without the replacement, the `1.` is a `DirectedInfinity[1.]`

Comment: While the idea sounds great, i only get all your output and no `BarLegend`anymore trying that approach. I must admit, besides puting a Frame around the `~Legend` I don't see much use in `LegendFunction -> `.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to Nasser M. Abbasi i found a way. To change the Display. The function that you can provide for any `~Legend` via `LegendFunction` wraps the complete `~Legend[]` into anything. And he mentioned, that `NumberForm` encapsulates the numbers. So why not replace them (delayed)?

### Version 1: Scientific Notation at every Label

Hence choosing

```
f[x_] := x /. {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> ScientificForm[y, 2]}
```

to replace any `NumberForm` in the Legend by `ScientificForm` (using my preferred two digits) we may call

```
BarLegend[{"LakeColors", N[1/10000 {-2, 2}]}, LegendFunction -> f]
```

and obtain

[image]

which is one of the desired results.

### Version 2: Extract exponent into the label

The first version might seem a little crowded for some Legends, so a nicer way would be to extract that Exponent from the `ScientificFormat` and change back to `NumberFormat` internally. While the first might also work, if the Range is implicitly given, this requires to know

```
{min, max} = 1/10000 {-2,10};
```

beforehand. Notice, that in this range, the Exponents of max ($10^{-3}$) and min ($-2\times10^{-4}$) differ.

We calculate

```
exp = Log[10, Max[Abs[min], Abs[max]]]
```

which is $-3$ here. And change the approach from before to

```
f[x_] := x /. {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> 
NumberForm[PaddedForm[y/(10^exp), {1, 2}], 2]}
```

That way we can add a Label to the `~Legend`, for containing this exponent, for example

```
BarLegend[{"LakeColors", {-min, max}}, LegendFunction -> f,
  LegendLabel -> Placed[DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox[ToString[" \[Times] 10"], exp]], Bottom]]
```

[image: Second approach using label]

Which I think is nicer than the first version, though you have to know the range of values beforehand. The space before `\[Times]` just places the label a little further to the right, such that it's bounded at the right hand side.

Comment: Further one could improve the numbers to all have same length using `f[x_] := x /. {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> ScientificForm[PaddedForm[y, {2, 2}], 2]}`

Comment: For the second formating idea (using `LegendLabel ->`) one challenge is, to unify the Labels to one Exponent (because ranging from `-2` to `10` is in `ScientificForm` an exponent with `0` and `1`. Second is, to obtain this exponent and print it in the Form `x10^c` in the Label.

Comment: Actually performing a further `Floor[exp]` is o good idea in order to get a decent scale (an not just $10^{-2.089744433}$ ;)

Comment: Hello. I am struggling to understand this code f[x_] := x /. {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> ScientificForm[y, 2]}. Could you explain what it does exactly ?

Comment: Sorry, after all these years (I stopped using Mathematica in 2013) I would have to look that up carefully, too.