# Scientific notation for legend labels

Tags: plotting, legending

I'd like to use scientific notation for the bar legend. I tried to follow the approach of this link: [Number format in Legend Labels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16750/number-format-in-legend-labels).

However, the `LegendFunction` did not work for my case (or, maybe, I did not use it correctly). The simple code, without any `LegendFunction`, is

```
DensityPlot[10^-4 Exp[(-x^2 - y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
PlotPoints -> 60,
ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, FontSize -> 12}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

The output plot is here:

[image]

But for the bar legend I prefer scientific notation, like $2.0\times 10^{-5}$ 
 (but not $2.0000\times 10^{-5}$) instead of $0.00002$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [referenced thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16767/22013):

```
f[x_] := x /. {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> ScientificForm[y, 2]}

DensityPlot[10^-4 Exp[(-x^2 - y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
PlotPoints -> 60, ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, FontSize -> 12}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], 
PlotLegends -> {LegendFunction -> f}]
```

[image]

or

```
f[x_] := x /. {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> ScientificForm[NumberForm[y, {2, 1}], 2]}
```

to get

[image]