# Is that possible to adjust the bar legend size in GraphicsGrid or DensityPlot automatically?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, grid-layouts

I'm using Mathematica 11.1. Consider the following code:

```
 f[x_] := x /. {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> 
 ScientificForm[PaddedForm[y, {2, 1}], 2]}
 W = 0.0001 Exp[-x^2 - y^2];

  DensityPlot[ W, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotPoints -> 60,
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[1 - (2 #/3 + 1/3)] &), 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Frame ->  True, 
  LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, FontSize -> 12},
  PlotRangePadding -> 0,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
   BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 330, LegendFunction -> f,
    LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {20, 0}}, LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 15}],
    Right]]
```

By trying different numbers, finally I could adjust the bar legend to the size of the plot: 
[image]
But if I remove the ticks of, say, y axis, the bar legend needs to be readjusted. Even worse is the GraphicsGrid. Consider the following codes:

```
f[x_] := x /. {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> 
ScientificForm[PaddedForm[y, {2, 1}], 2]}


W = 0.1 Exp[-x^2 - y^2];

p1 = DensityPlot[ W, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 60,
MaxRecursion -> 15, PlotRange -> All, 
ColorFunction ->(Hue[1 - (2 #/3 + 1/3)] &), 
FrameLabel -> {Style["", FontSlant -> Italic, FontSize -> 16], 
  Style["y", FontSlant -> Italic, FontSize -> 16]}, 
LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, FontSize -> 12}, Frame ->  True, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12],
PlotRangePadding -> 0,
FrameTicks -> {{{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, None}, {None, None}},
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 32}, PlotLegends -> Placed[
 BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 160, LegendFunction -> f,
  LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {20, -5}}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> {10, 15}], Right]];

p2 = DensityPlot[.1 W, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 60,
ColorFunction -> (Hue[1 - (2 #/3 + 1/3)] &), 
FrameLabel -> {Style["", FontSlant -> Italic, FontSize -> 16], 
 Style["", FontSlant -> Italic, FontSize -> 16]}, 
LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, FontSize -> 12}, Frame ->  True, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12],
PlotRangePadding -> 0,
FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, None}},
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 32}, PlotLegends -> Placed[
 BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 160, LegendFunction -> f,
  LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {20, -5}}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> {10, 15}], Right]];

p3 = DensityPlot[.01 W, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 60, 
ColorFunction -> (Hue[1 - (2 #/3 + 1/3)] &), 
FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSlant -> Italic, FontSize -> 16], 
 Style["y", FontSlant -> Italic, FontSize -> 16]}, 
LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, FontSize -> 12}, Frame ->  True, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12],
PlotRangePadding -> 0,
FrameTicks -> {{{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, None}, {{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, 
  None}},
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 32}, PlotLegends -> Placed[
 BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 160, LegendFunction -> f,
  LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {20, -5}}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> {10, 15}], Right]];

p4 = DensityPlot[ .001 W, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 60,
ColorFunction -> (Hue[1 - (2 #/3 + 1/3)] &), 
FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSlant -> Italic, FontSize -> 16], ""},
LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, FontSize -> 12}, Frame ->  True, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12],
PlotRangePadding -> 0,
FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, None}},
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 32}, PlotLegends -> Placed[
BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 160, LegendFunction -> f,
 LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {20, -5}}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> {10, 15}], Right]];
```

With the help of the following link, I could adjust the plots manually: 
[Aligning plot axes in a graphics object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4059/aligning-plot-axes-in-a-graphics-object).

```
GraphicsGrid[{{Show[p1, 
ImagePadding -> {{40, 5}, {Automatic, Automatic}}], 
Show[p2, 
ImagePadding -> {{40, 5}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]}, {Show[p3, 
ImagePadding -> {{40, 5}, {Automatic, Automatic}}], 
Show[p4, ImagePadding -> {{40, 5}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]}}, 
ImageSize -> Large, Spacings -> {-100, -180}]
```

And the result is 
[image]

Despite that I had adjusted the legend bars manually, I had to change the size of bar legend again, otherwise the  bar legends merge! If I choose a proper size (160 in my case), the GraphisGrid gives a misaligned figure yet because I used the same size for all plots, but as I remove the ticks of one axis, the size must be rescaled. Moreover, the ticks of bar legends are ugly. It would be much nicer if the exponent (i.e, $\times 10^x$) is on the top of each bar.This is explained in this link: [Number format in Legend Labels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16750/number-format-in-legend-labels). However, I tried that, and it did not work.

In summary:
1) Is that possible to adjust the bar legend to the size of figure automatically?
2) How should I change my codes so that the bar legends are aligned after using GraphicsGrid?
3) How can I put the exponent of the bar legends on the top of each bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     {min, max} = 1/100000 {0, 10};
     exp = Log[10, Max[Abs[min], Abs[max]]]
      f[x_] := x /. {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> 
    NumberForm[PaddedForm[y/(10^exp), {1, 2}], 2]}
    W = 0.0001 Exp[-x^2 - y^2];
    p1 = DensityPlot[W, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 60, 
     MaxRecursion -> 15, PlotRange -> All, 
    ColorFunction -> (Hue[1 - (2 #/3 + 1/3)] &), 
    FrameLabel -> {Style["", FontSlant -> Italic, FontSize -> 16], 
    Style["y", FontSlant -> Italic, FontSize -> 16]}, 
   LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, FontSize -> 12}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12], PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, None}, {None, None}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 32}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{Automatic, {-min, max}}, LegendFunction -> f, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 145, LegendFunction -> f, 
  LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {20, -5}}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {10, 15}, 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Placed[DisplayForm[
    SuperscriptBox[ToString[" \[Times] 10"], exp]], Top]]];

    GraphicsGrid[{{Show[p1, ImagePadding -> {{32, 12}, {38, 8}}], 
    Show[p2, ImagePadding -> {{32, 12}, {38, 8}}]}, {Show[p3, 
    ImagePadding -> {{32, 12}, {38, 8}}], 
    Show[p4, ImagePadding -> {{32, 12}, {38, 8}}]}}, ImageSize -> 590, 
    Spacings -> {-120, -180}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: The ticks on y axis are not appeared. As I noticed, one has to adjust the sizes manually. For example, you have chosen  LegendMarkerSize -> 320.

Comment: Moreover, the bar legends are not adjusted perfectly. For example, in the first and second rows, the bottom of bar legends has a different spacing respect to the bottom of plots.

Comment: Now, you can see spacing of barlegend w.r.t bottom of plot are same.